# Bash script which can handle \x00 "chars"

Tags: bash, binary, echo, send

```
    PAYLOAD=`cat $f`
    header=`cat a.hex`
    send=$header$PAYLOAD           #The actual Payload
    echo -en $send | nc -p 3300 127.0.0.1 4000 &
```

`PAYLOAD` contains a simple string

`header` contains `"\x00" "\x01"` ... etc in binary

`echo` can't send the `\x00` chars.

Some of the chars are sent for example `\x01  \x11  \x10...` but not the `\x00`

How to `echo` or `read` or `cat` (etc) and give it to the nc without losing the `\x00` characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cat a.hex $f | ...
```

instead of saying:

```
PAYLOAD=`cat $f`
header=`cat a.hex`
send=$header$PAYLOAD           #The actual Payload
echo -en $send | ...
```